# Getting an area when dealing with a undefined edge of domain. $f(x)=\frac{x}{|x|}$

Tags: calculus

Say you have the function $$f(x)=\frac{x}{|x|}$$

Consider $$\int_{-2}^0{f(x)}dx$$

This graph is undefined at 0, so the rectangle formed does not technically ever reach x=0 ?  So, is the area on that section equal to -2 or -1.99999999.... ?

[image]

Comment: So the question is whether or not this integral depends on a single undefined point?  A good place to start is how do you define integrals.

Comment: Anti-derivative?  Area under a curve with infinitely thin rectangles ?

Comment: And how does that work out?

Comment: I don't know.  You still can't go to the very edge, but I guess you're saying it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  More specifically there is no difference between $-2$ and $-1.999...$.  You can define it as an improper integral and by taking the limit as the upper bound goes to $0$ you will get $-2$.

Comment: You don't even need limits.  Taking the Riemann sum directly should suffice.

Comment: No you can't.  Riemann sums required the integrand to be defined on the interval.  Obviously this is easily remediable but the easiest way to explain it for OP is as an improper integral.

Comment: I don't know how to set this up as an improper integral.   Nothing is going to infinity.  It's just going from -2 to 0.   Not seeing where infinity becomes one of the integral limits.

Comment: An improper integral doesn't require it to go to infinity.  You can also use an improper integral when there is a removable discontinuity in the domain of the integrand.  This is a removable discontinuity.  It is an endpoint of the domain of the integrand so the limit only has to exist from one side.  Note that this isn't very rigorous but it will work in most cases.

Comment: So, all I do to my original question is to make it a limit problem where x -> 0, and change the integral to go from -2 to x,  right?

Comment: @JackOfAll That's exactly right.

Comment: @lordoftheshadows I edited my OP.  Does that solution look correct?

Comment: @JackOfAll You've got it pretty much right but use a different variable for the limit because you're already using x in the integrand.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $f(x) = -1$ for all $x\in[-2,0)$. In fact, the only subset of $[-2,0]$ for which $f(x)\neq -1$ is $S:=\{0\}$, because $f(0)$ is undefined. However, as $\mathcal{L}^1(S) = 0$, we can alter the value of $f(x)$ on this set without changing the value of our integral, as one can for any set of Lebesgue measure $0$.

For instance, consider $g(x) = -1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, and observe that $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x\in[-2,0]\backslash S$.

Thus

$$\int_{-2}^0 f(x)dx = \int_{-2}^0 g(x)dx = -2$$

Comment: While your answer is correct and rigorous I don't really think this is what OP is looking for.

Comment: Yeah, thought about that as well after I posted the answer. Honestly, since I'm currently doing Lebesgue integrals up and down at university, this was the first thing that popped into my head, and I didn't even consider thinking in terms of Riemann integrals initially.

Comment: Still it's something that worth having since it could be useful for someone else who comes along.